ErrorDocument 403 request handling
Hello I've created an error.html file in /var/www/error_page/ to display this page in the case of a 403 error.
and my /var/www/html/wordpress/.htaccess file looks like this

order allow,deny

allow from my_ip

ErrorDocument 403 /var/www/error_page/error.html

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

When I want to access my site from outside the network, I get this page and not the one I want
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access this resource.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Apache/2.4.59 (Debian) Server at example.com Port 443

Thank you in advance for your help
Edit : /var/log/apache2/error.log content
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:36.157862 2024] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae98478/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/wordpress/var -> /var/www/html/wordpress/var/www/error_page/error.html
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:36.157883 2024] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae98478/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/wordpress/var/www/error_page/error.html -> var/www/error_page/error.html
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:36.157888 2024] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae98478/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'var/www/error_page/error.html'
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:36.157909 2024] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae98478/initial/redir#1] setting env variable 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' to ''
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:36.157915 2024] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae98478/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/wordpress/var -> /var/www/html/wordpress/var/www/error_page/error.html
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:36.157936 2024] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae98478/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/wordpress/var/www/error_page/error.html -> var/www/error_page/error.html
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:36.157942 2024] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae98478/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] applying pattern '^index\\.php$' to uri 'var/www/error_page/error.html'
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:36.157948 2024] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae98478/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/wordpress/var -> /var/www/html/wordpress/var/www/error_page/error.html
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:36.157952 2024] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae98478/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/wordpress/var/www/error_page/error.html -> var/www/error_page/error.html
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:36.157957 2024] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae98478/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] applying pattern '.' to uri 'var/www/error_page/error.html'
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:36.157989 2024] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae98478/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/html/wordpress/var' pattern='!-f' => matched
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:36.157996 2024] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae98478/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/html/wordpress/var' pattern='!-d' => matched
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:36.158012 2024] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae98478/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] rewrite 'var/www/error_page/error.html' -> '/index.php'
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:36.158018 2024] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae98478/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/html/wordpress/ with /
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:36.158022 2024] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae98478/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] trying to replace context docroot /var/www/html/wordpress with context prefix 
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:36.158026 2024] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae98478/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT]
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:36.158157 2024] [authz_core:error] [pid 187855] [client 198.0.x.x:61666] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/wordpress/index.php
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:37.057117 2024] [authz_core:error] [pid 187855] [client 198.0.x.x:61666] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/wordpress/favicon.ico, referer: https://example.com/
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:37.057194 2024] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae96480/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/wordpress/var -> /var/www/html/wordpress/var/www/error_page/error.html, referer: https://example.com/
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:37.057202 2024] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae96480/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/wordpress/var/www/error_page/error.html -> var/www/error_page/error.html, referer: https://example.com/
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:37.057207 2024] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae96480/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] applying pattern '.*' to uri 'var/www/error_page/error.html', referer: https://example.com/
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:37.057216 2024] [rewrite:trace5] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae96480/initial/redir#1] setting env variable 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' to '', referer: https://example.com/
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:37.057221 2024] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae96480/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/wordpress/var -> /var/www/html/wordpress/var/www/error_page/error.html, referer: https://example.com/
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:37.057251 2024] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae96480/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/wordpress/var/www/error_page/error.html -> var/www/error_page/error.html, referer: https://example.com/
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:37.057256 2024] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae96480/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] applying pattern '^index\\.php$' to uri 'var/www/error_page/error.html', referer: https://example.com/
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:37.057260 2024] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae96480/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] add path info postfix: /var/www/html/wordpress/var -> /var/www/html/wordpress/var/www/error_page/error.html, referer: https://example.com/
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:37.057265 2024] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae96480/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] strip per-dir prefix: /var/www/html/wordpress/var/www/error_page/error.html -> var/www/error_page/error.html, referer: https://example.com/
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:37.057269 2024] [rewrite:trace3] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae96480/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] applying pattern '.' to uri 'var/www/error_page/error.html', referer: https://example.com/
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:37.057277 2024] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae96480/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/html/wordpress/var' pattern='!-f' => matched, referer: https://example.com/
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:37.057283 2024] [rewrite:trace4] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae96480/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] RewriteCond: input='/var/www/html/wordpress/var' pattern='!-d' => matched, referer: https://example.com/
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:37.057287 2024] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae96480/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] rewrite 'var/www/error_page/error.html' -> '/index.php', referer: https://example.com/
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:37.057293 2024] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae96480/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] trying to replace prefix /var/www/html/wordpress/ with /, referer: https://example.com/
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:37.057298 2024] [rewrite:trace2] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae96480/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] trying to replace context docroot /var/www/html/wordpress with context prefix , referer: https://example.com/
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:37.057302 2024] [rewrite:trace1] [pid 187855] mod_rewrite.c(493): [client 198.0.x.x:61666] 198.0.x.x - - [example.com/sid#7f3dccf27a70][rid#7f3dcae96480/initial/redir#1] [perdir /var/www/html/wordpress/] internal redirect with /index.php [INTERNAL REDIRECT], referer: https://example.com/
[Sat Jul 06 08:57:37.057360 2024] [authz_core:error] [pid 187855] [client 198.0.x.x:61666] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: /var/www/html/wordpress/index.php, referer: https://example.com/


You only allow from my_ip.
If you want to authorize specific ip or range of ip you need to add
 Require ip 192.168.*.*/24
 Require ip my_ip
 Require ip 127.0.0.1

And remove
order allow,deny

allow from my_ip

Plus for the 403 error on the 403 page you need to give apache read permission to the error_page directory or add an .htaccess file with the same require all granted directive

Thank you @alessandro for your reply. I need to display this page only to people not authorized to access my page (I have a list of IP addresses to authorize). And I've already run this command to authorize access to all sudo chmod 777 /var/www/error_page/ (I apologize if it's not clear, I'm quite a beginner)

Edited the answer

Thanks @Alessandro, but I still get the same error message even though I've done what you suggested. sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/error_page/error.html
sudo chown www-data:www-data /var/www/error_page

Did you create the .htaccess in error page directory with the require ip

Yes, and I've added lines with only require ip (Ex: Require ip 198.x.x.x).

Did you checked the path and the file in both, file system and config file?

Yes, the error.html page is located in /var/www/error_page. And in this folder I created an .htaccess file in which I only filled in the Require ip my_ip line and in /var/www/html/wordpress/.htaccess, I made the modifications following your recommendations.

On the other hand, for "file system and config file", I don't really feel it, unfortunately.

Try in error config with Require all granted

I always get the error message **Forbidden
You don't have permission to access this resource.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
Apache/2.4.59 (Debian) Server at example.com Port 443**

Then try enable the max apache loglevel (which is trace8) and see what came up

I'm not getting a trace8 log, but I've just edited the description to add the contents of the action.log
